# how to loop with a combination of while and for

Tags: python, loops

how to loop using while and for

```
from random import random

a = int(input("MASUKAN ANGKA :"))
for i in range(a):
        bil = random()
        print("Perulangan ke- :", bil)
```

Example run:

```
MASUKAN ANGKA :5
Perulangan ke- : 0.0813806069084485
Perulangan ke- : 0.5072770244491718
Perulangan ke- : 0.8493965282202113
Perulangan ke- : 0.43884806653052943
Perulangan ke- : 0.7745391208748537
```

Comment: Hi Bayu Satrio, welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your question to adjust the tags and format the code a bit better, please check that I got everything correct. With respect to the question you've asked, I'm afraid it is not very clear what you want to change. You say you want to add a `while` loop, I guess, but I have no idea where or what you expect it to do. Can you [edit] your post to more clearly specify why you think you need a `while` loop? What you want your code to do differently than what it currently does?

Comment: what do you want to achieve with the code? i guess there's no need to use while loop if you are achieving what you want.

Comment: Or maybe, do you want to know how to use while loop to get the same result?

Comment: What is the aim?? I didn't understand your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that in while loop, this is the answer.

```
from random import random

a = int(input("MASUKAN ANGKA :"))
while (a > 0):# runs a times
    bil = random() # gives the random number
    print("Perulangan ke- :", bil) #
    a -= 1
```

Comment: Hey! You too copied my idea

Comment: @Swagrim where??

Comment: From my comment on this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to do here, if not with a *combination* of for and while loops.

I can only assume that you want a while loop version of your code, which goes like this:

```
from random import random

a = int(input("MASUKAN ANGKA :"))
while (a > 0):
    bil = random()
    print("Perulangan ke- :", bil)
    a -= 1
```

All you have to do is decrement the input with each loop until it equals 0.

Comment: Haha! Copied my idea!

Comment: You forgot to comment the same under the other guy's code!

Comment: You seem to be a funny guy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine both loops, you can use the for loop inside an infinite loop:

```
from random import random

a = int(input("MASUKAN ANGKA :")) 
while (True):
    for i in range(a):
        bil = random()
        print("Perulangan ke- :", bil)
    break
```